# Given two msbuild log events X and Y where X.Timestamp < Y.Timestamp is it true that event X started running before the event Y?

Tags: msbuild

We are talking about parallel build. The two events are the following:

- MSBuild `TaskStarted`
- `ProjectStarted`

OR

- `ProjectFinished`
- MSBuild `TaskFinished`

So if MSBuild `TaskStarted.Timestamp` < `ProjectStarted.Timestamp`, then the MSBuild task in question started earlier than the project.

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to establish parent-child relationship between msbuild events. The trickiest is between MSBuild `TaskStarted` and `ProjectStarted`. The `TaskStarted` (i.e. the task) can be the parent of the given `ProjectStarted` (i.e. the project), but in the log they often have the same timestamp and belong to different msbuild nodes. I am still able to correlate between them using another assumption I make ([Is it true that `ProjectStartedEventArgs.TargetNames` is identical for all the child projects invoked from the same MSBuild task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301962/is-it-true-that-projectstartedeventargs-targetnames-is-identical-for-all-the-c)). Whoever, I have cases where my code breaks, because it seems that a child  `ProjectStarted` event has smaller timestamp than its parent MSBuild `TaskStarted` event.

Comment: With 'triggered', you actually mean 'triggered' (as in, some kind of signal was given that something can start which might not necessarily be the same as actually having started) or rather 'executed' or 'started'?

Comment: I added clarifications

Comment: Skimming through the source code, I'd say it might depend on the time difference: if it's like seconds earlier, then yes it probably did start earlier. Reason: as fas as I can tell the timestamp in the log event gets created right before the task gets executed. However it seems that execution might actually take place on another thread so it could be possible X gets logged, then Y gets logged, then Y starts, then X starts. But I assume the timestamps would be very close though. But maybe if you clarify what you actually want to know there might be other ways than timestamps..

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable way to establish parent-child relationship between MSBuild events is by using the `BuildEventContext`. Each `BuildEventArgs` has a `BuildEventContext`:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Build.Framework/BuildEventArgs.cs,3ad27845b97a06b4

In it you can see the Node ID, which Project this event belongs to, which target (if any) and which task (if any). If the task is MSBuild (starts a build of another project) then the project's parent Task will point to that MSBuild task.

I wouldn't necessarily rely on timestamps to establish relationships, maybe only for temporal ordering (to display the events in the right logical order).

Comment: I am doing exactly this. However, I witness a situation where many events arrive with exactly the same timestamp and they include multiple instances of MSBuild TaskStarted/TaskFinished and ProjectStarted/ProjectFinished events and there are more than one Project event that can match more than one Task event based on the NodeId and ParentId comparison. The problem is that `ParentBuildEventContext` does not contain the respective `TaskId` value, only the NodeId and Project{Instance,Context}Id, which are not enough to disambiguate.

Comment: This could be an MSBuild limitation - consider perhaps filing an MSBuild issue? https://github.com/Microsoft/MSBuild/issues

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3939 Unfortunately, I still cannot provide more information. Working on it.