# Is it true that `ProjectStartedEventArgs.TargetNames` is identical for all the child projects invoked from the same MSBuild task?

Tags: msbuild

On the surface, this should be the case, because the Projects passed to the MSBuild task share the same value of the `MSBuild.Targets` property, but I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be true, here's the source code:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/IntrinsicTasks/MSBuild.cs,288

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/6fa296fcf692bf61e374d93826c30ca124c23479/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/IntrinsicTasks/MSBuild.cs#L288